# Will Variable lose it's value when thread sleeps for long time

Tags: c#

```
private void Test(string param)
     {
         Thread.Sleep(OneDay);
         Submit(param);

     }
```

This is console application. Is there a possibility that param might lose it's value if the thread sleeps for long time?

Comment: Why would you even think that?

Comment: while the answer is no, you're still better off using scheduled tasks rather than sleeping for an entire day as you need to worry about things like the computer being restarted, the process being killed by someone else, consuming system resources for a day when you really don't need to, etc.

Comment: If the computer is at very high altitude, cosmic rays may corrupt the stack.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman but then you have to worry about the stack becoming either stretchy, rocky, invisible or burst into flames.

Comment: @ConradFrix: and running off to do battle with Dr. Doom, leaving you with no stack at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility that param might lose it's value if the thread sleeps for long time?

No. `param` is on the stack and once the execution resumes it will be popped back off from the stack.

Comment: Also param is immutable. Its conceivable that the "contents" of a mutable reference type could change but that's confusing the value of a reference type and its "contents"

Answer (score 1):

No. Each thread will have it's own stack. When thread is back from sleep, it will use variable from the stack.